# InvokeHTTP processor Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have to invoke multiple Endpoints with the "same" user credentials (basic auth). I don't want to hard code "Basic Auth UserName" and "Basic Auth Password" for **each** InvokeHttp header. Is there a easy way to maintain it in one place and pass it to each InvokeHttp processor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using NiFi 1.10.0 or newer, then you can create a parameter context with parameters for "basic.auth.user" and a sensitive parameter for "basic.auth.password", then bind the parameter context to the process group, then in the processor reference #{basic.auth.user} and #{basic.auth.password}.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Parameters

If older than 1.10.0, then you can user expression language to reference a variable, system property, or environment variable.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan for the response.  I'm using 1.9.0. "Basic Authentication Password" doesn't support expression language. How do I go about passing "variable" to sensitive value which doesn't support expression language.

Comment: There is not a good way, that is one reason why parameters were added so that it can be done from any property no matter what